# Android dialog rotation issue.

Tags: android, dialog

I have a `Dialog` which depends on information from the current view. This works fine until the unit is rotated at which point the dialog tries to display before the view is built. The dialog is non essential and I'm happy to scrap it on rotation rather than try to replicate the information and hold it for the dialog to be reconstructed.

I've tried calling  `removeDialog(PHOTO_CREDIT_DIALOG)` from the activities `onPause` method but it doesn't seem to do anything. I've also held a reference to the dialog and tried calling `dismiss()` in `onPause`. Also to no avail. The same call when run from a button on the dialog does infact remove it.

thanks, 
m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `onPause` get called ?  What if you try to remove the Dialog in `onConfigurationChanged` instead?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the onConfigurationChanged approach. On Pause does get called but nothing seems to happen with the dismiss.